# return n smallest indexes by column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following (simplified) dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10],
'Y': [10,20,30,40,50,-10,-20,-30,-40,-50],
'Z': [20,18,16,14,12,10,8,6,4,2]},index=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
```

Which gives the following:

```
    X   Y   Z
A   1  10  20
B   2  20  18
C   3  30  16
D   4  40  14
E   5  50  12
F   6 -10  10
G   7 -20   8
H   8 -30   6
I   9 -40   4
J  10 -50   2
```

I want to create a new dataframe that returns the index of the n smallest values, by column.

Desired output (say, 3 smallest values):

```
   X  Y  Z
0  A  J  J
1  B  I  I
2  C  H  H
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Faster numpy solution with [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
N = 3
a = np.argsort(-df.values, axis=0)[-1:-1-N:-1]
print (a)
[[0 9 9]
 [1 8 8]
 [2 7 7]]

b = pd.DataFrame(df.index[a], columns=df.columns)
print (b)
   X  Y  Z
0  A  J  J
1  B  I  I
2  C  H  H
```

**Timings**:

```
In [111]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df.index[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=0)[-1:-1-N:-1]], columns=df.columns))
159 µs ± 1.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [112]: %timeit (df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.nsmallest(N).index)))
3.52 ms ± 49.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This solution no longer works as of now.
Relations matrix is calculated correctly, but second step results only in throwing `ValueError: Multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. obj[:, None]) is no longer supported. Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead.`
I don't get how to salvage this...

Comment: @PaulAlex - solution is `b = pd.DataFrame(df.index.to_numpy()[a], columns=df.columns)`

Answer (score 12):

You can use `apply` with [`nsmallest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html):

```
n = 3
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.nsmallest(n).index))

#   X   Y   Z
#0  A   J   J
#1  B   I   I
#2  C   H   H
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to sort your input dataframe per column, then get a list of all of the indices of each column, create a dataframe from these indices, then return the top n rows from the resultant dataframe.

```
def topN(df, n):
#first, sort dataframe per column
sort_x = df.sort_values(by = ['X'], ascending = True)
sort_y = df.sort_values(by = ['Y'], ascending = True)
sort_z = df.sort_values(by = ['Z'], ascending = True)
#now get a list of the indices of each sorted df
index_list_x = sort_x.index.values.tolist()
index_list_y = sort_y.index.values.tolist()
index_list_z = sort_z.index.values.tolist()
#create dataframe from lists
sorted_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'sorted_x':index_list_x,
     'sorted_y':index_list_y,
     'sorted_z':index_list_z  
    })
#return the top n from the sorted dataframe
return sorted_df.iloc[0:n]

topN(df,3)
```

Returns:

```
  X  Y  Z
0 A  J  J
1 B  I  I
2 C  H  H
```