# Finding highest n values of every column in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to find the highest 3 values of each column in a dataframe, and return the index names, ordered by value. The dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"u1":[1,2,-3,4,5],
                   "u2":[8,-4,5,6,7],
                   "u3":[np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]},
                   index=["q1","q2","q3","q4","q5"])
```

The result would look like this:

```
u1   u2   u3
q5   q1   NaN
q4   q5   NaN
q2   q4   NaN
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return n smallest indexes by column using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193131/return-n-smallest-indexes-by-column-using-pandas). Adopting it to largest instead of smallest should be trivial.

Comment: Yes it does, thanks for finding it! However, I did not find it when searching for an answer. Maybe because it's min not max. Would it be helpful for people searching for an answer, to leave this question in, or not?

Comment: Everything is fine as it is now. Having a couple of duplicates doesn't hurt especially when they are titled differently. It's even possible that your question will eventually become more popular than the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`pandas.Series.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) function.

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.nlargest(3).index))
   u1  u2   u3
0  q5  q1  NaN
1  q4  q5  NaN
2  q2  q4  NaN
```

Answer (score 4):

We need do `stack` then `sort_values` and create the new index use `cumcount`, and `pivot` to reshape it back

```
s=df.stack().reset_index().sort_values(0,ascending=False).\
          assign(index=lambda x : x.groupby('level_1').cumcount()).\
           pivot('index','level_1','level_0').\
            reindex(columns=df.columns).head(3)
Out[308]: 
       u1  u2  u3
index            
0      q5  q1 NaN
1      q4  q5 NaN
2      q2  q4 NaN
```